# How to connect 2 VPC's that are 3rd party running your managed services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

Here's the scenario I'm trying to resolve.
First, we have our VPC running services.
Second, we have manage Clickhouse service running in ClickHouse Cloud.
Finally, we have a manage Kafka service running in Aiven.

VPC Peering is configured for our VPC and Aiven's VPC.  Also have a PSC setup between our VPC and the Kafka service in Aiven VPC.

Have a PSC setup between our VPC and the ClickHouse service running in ClickHouse Cloud.

My problem is I would like to be able to connect the ClickHouse service in ClickHouse Cloud to the Kafka Service in Aiven.

Is this even possible?

Comment: As written, I do not understand your problem or your network connectivity and routing requirements. Did you attempt to enable VPC Peering between ClickHouse and Kafka? If yes, what is the problem? Do any of the VPC's addresses overlap? Note: VPC peering does not provide transitive routing. [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#spec-general). Note: Private Service Connect will not help you connect to your services together. Edit your post and clearly define your problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. I have updated the question, hope it's more clear.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `ClickHouse` was your Google Cloud project name. I have no idea as I have not used their service. However, you have not described a problem to solve, only a general description of what you want. Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of now, ClickHouse Cloud can't be configured to make VPC PSC connection as a client.